# Load string that's not quite JSON in Python

Tags: python

I am receiving a response from a service in text format  unfortunately I cannot ask them to send me in JSON format) below is the reponse:

```
'{message: Successfully sent data for processing, execId: d03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c}'
```

I want to either convert this to dict or json but I am unable to do so, as the string inside the '{ }' does not have single or double quotes.

I have tried using `json.loads()`, `json.dumps()`, `ast.literal()` and also few other methods, but was not able to achieve the desired output.

The output desired is:

```
{'message': 'Successfully sent data for processing', 'execId' : 'd03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c' }
```

Comment: what you have tried ?

Comment: @VikasDamodar I have tries json.load('{message: hello how are you, exceID: abc123-tyhx}') but throws me an error. Also tried ast.literal('{message: hello how are you, exceID: abc123-tyhx}')

Comment: I have made an attempt solve your issue, you can check in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = '{message: Successfully sent data for processing, execId: d03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c}'
// actual string message: Successfully sent data for processing, execId: d03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c

    data_str = data[1:-1]
    t_arr = data_str.split(',')
    data_dict = {}
    for data in t_arr : 
        temp = data.split(':')
        data_dict[str(temp[0].strip())] = str(temp[1].strip())

    print data_dict
```

Answer (score 2):

With a bit of string manipulation you can convert like:

#### Code:

```
def my_convert(a_string):
    convert = a_string.replace(
        ': ', '": "').replace(
        '}', '"}').replace(
        ', ', '", "').replace(
        '{', '{"')

    return json.loads(convert)
```

#### Test Code:

```
import json
data = '{message: Successfully sent data for processing, ' \
       'execId: d03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c}'

print(my_convert(data))
```

#### Results:

```
{'message': 'Successfully sent data for processing', 'execId': 'd03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c'}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response but there is a small catch, there are two key 'message' and 'execId', but as the above code I get only message key.

Answer (score 1):

Here a code you can try, Don't know pythonic or not :

```
g = '{message: Successfully sent data for processing, execId: d03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c}'
a = []
for i in g.split(","):
    a.append(i.strip("{}").split(":"))
b = {}
for j in a:
   b.update({j[i]: j[i+1] for i in range(0, len(j), 2)})
print(b)
```

it will give the o/p like this :

```
{'message': ' Successfully sent data for processing', ' execId': ' d03c96hg-4098-47b9-9e4b-3cb2c'}
```